# Codename One Javascript port: get host and port

Tags: codenameone

Is there an easy way in a Codename One app built as Javascript to get the current host and the port, without implementing a Javascript native interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to ask Steve who gave the answer. Yes you can via display properties specifically: `browser.window.location.host` and `browser.window.location.port`

See https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-javascript.html#environment_variables